# UI freezes while adding items inside the ListView in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8, .net-4.5

I am using `ListView` to populate items inside it. I have a search box which I use to send a request to the server and get the data. The response data from the server will be added to the `ListView`. When I continuously sends a request to the server, I keep getting the data and updates the `ListView`. This causes UI freezing problem while updating. So, when I type something inside the search box, UI freezes until the `ListView` update finishes. Can anybody please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Try by adding `listBox.BeginUpdate()` and `listBox.EndUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your main thread is blocked for the time between request and responce.
You should run requests to server in separate thread

```
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
     {
        //your request here
         listView1.add()
     });
```

Comment: I have found that it's not happening while sending and receiving the response. It happens only when the response data is updated to the ListView.

Comment: It can easily be reproduced in a sample app by just having a textbox and ListView control. Just type something in the textbox and update the ListView. You will see that while typing quickly in the textbox, UI will freeze sometimes due to the update happening in the ListView. I am updating the ListView after 50 ms I type something in the textbox. But in my actual app, the timer interval is set to 300 ms and still that freezing issue is happening.

Comment: Is this not updating the UI on a separate thread? Would that not throw a cross threading exception?

Comment: @HaemEternal maybe in debugger, but shouldn't be thrown at normal run.